# CHEF: HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-cloudformation, berkshelf

I am trying to automate aws ec2 memcached instance bootstrapping by executing memcached chef recipe. I am invoking a shell script name cache-init.sh from the cloud formation UserData section. I have following steps in my shell scripts:

I am running AMI RHEL 6.7 version

```
!/bin/bash

init () {
BINARIES=/root/.binaries
PROFILE_SCRIPT=/etc/profile.d/instance_profile.sh
APPLICATION_RELEASE_VERSION="app-v3.0.1"
CHEF_ZIP="app-chef-${APPLICATION_RELEASE_VERSION}.zip"
APP_FILES="${CHEF_ZIP}"
HOME=/root
}

# Initializing the script vairables.
 init

# Create chef folders
 mkdir /root/.chef;
 mkdir /root/.metadata;

# Disable rhui-lb plugin, this has an issue in RHEL within VPC
 sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhui-lb.conf

# Print all environment varialbes in log
 set > /root/.metadata/metadata.txt


# Update ${PROFILE_SCRIPT}
 echo "export HOME=${HOME}" >> ${PROFILE_SCRIPT};
 chmod 644 ${PROFILE_SCRIPT};
 log 'Added ${PROFILE_SCRIPT}';

 echo ${HOME}

# Install chef
# Set these just for Chef installation
/usr/bin/curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash -s -- -v    11.16.2-1;
chef_version=`chef-solo --version`;
log "Installed Chef Version : $chef_version in /opt/chef " ;

log "Installing ChefDk"
/usr/bin/curl -L https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -c current -P chefdk

chef-repo=/root/.chef/chef-repo
memcached_cookbook=${chef-repo}/cookbooks/memcached
cd ${memcached_cookbook}


# download and package the dependencies.
chef exec berks install
chef exec berks vendor

log "memcached dependencies downloaded and packaged"

cp -r berks-cookbooks/runit /root/.chef/itduzzit/cookbooks
cp -r berks-cookbooks/yum /root/.chef/itduzzit/cookbooks
cp -r berks-cookbooks/yum-epel /root/.chef/itduzzit/cookbooks
cp -r berks-cookbooks/packagecloud /root/.chef/itduzzit/cookbooks

# Clean up the dependencies.
rm -rf berks-cookbooks
```

After the berks install command gets executed, I get following error:

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rb-readline-0.5.3/lib/rbreadline.rb:1097:in <module:RbReadline>: HOME environment variable   (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory (RuntimeError)
 from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rb-readline-    0.5.3/lib/rbreadline.rb:17:in <top (required)>
 from ...
 from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/berkshelf-4.3.2/bin/berks:3:in `<top (required)>'
 from /usr/bin/berks:49:in `load'
 from /usr/bin/berks:49:in `<main>'
```

I tried setting the HOME env variable by exporting it at the start of the cache-init.sh script but still got the same error. When I ssh to the box and run the script manually, it works fine. I tried searching for the error but did not find suitable fix. Would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Please show how you set the environment variable.

Comment: @coderanger I have updated the question with my script.

Answer (score 0):

Under init, that should be `export HOME=...` (and the same for everything else. Without the `export` you are creating a bash variable but not an environment variable.

Comment: I am exporting the variable by saving in /etc/profile.d/instance_profile.sh by using the below command: `echo "export HOME=${HOME}" >> ${PROFILE_SCRIPT};`

Comment: That has no effect on commands later in the same script, and generally speaking has no effect on services or other non-interactive sessions at all.

Comment: My issue got resolved, thanks for your help, initially as I was writing the `export HOME=/root in the /etc/profile.d/instance_profile.sh` which I realized later that it is only sourced at shell startup. Since my script was directly called by cloud formation script, it never got sourced resulting in the error.

I changed my script and explicitly did `export HOME=/root` in the script body which made it available as environment variable for berkshelf's berks command and fixed the issue.

Appreciate your help!